# Illegal character '0xa0' in xml

Tags: xml, parsing

I am reading an xml file from Git and using it as as request to rest.

I am getting error Illegal character '0xa0' at offset .....

I tried to replace the characters using 
replaceAll("[\x00-\x09\x11\x12\x14-\x1F\x7F]", "") before sending the request.
But still same error.

What exact character '0xa0' is and do i need to remove or encode it?

Comment: 0xa0 is not in the given range, so no wonder it wasn't removed. In latin-1, it's used to encode non-breakable space.

Comment: So its hard space " ", how can I remove undesired space, as xml contains valid space also.

Comment: The answer at the duplicate link has regex examples in several languages for matching/removing characters not allowed in XML.